# Create Audio Downloader method with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, download

I recently created an ImageDownloader method with Asynctask now I need exactly the same method for downloading audio in my current project.. Can you kindly help me with editing this method !?

*(If I have some mistakes here please correct me as I am new in android)*

This is my ImageDownloader AsynkTask :

```
    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute(); 

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
             getClass().getName());
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading...");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while your file is downloading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(100);



        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... image_urls) {
         int count = 0;
        try {  

             URL url = new URL(image_urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            conn.setDoInput(true);   
            conn.connect();     
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            while(count != 100){
                publishProgress(""+count);
                count +=5;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {       
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }

        return null;   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.v("count",progress[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }     

@Override       
protected void onPostExecute(String args) {

             mWakeLock.release();      
             File showPathInToast;
             File filename;
             try {
                 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                 Log.i("in save()", "after mkdir");
                 new File(path + "/Dastak/News").mkdirs();

                 String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                 String imageFileName = timeStamp;

                 filename = new File(path + "/Dastak/News/"+ imageFileName +".jpg");
                 showPathInToast = new File(path + "/Dastak/News/");

                 Log.i("in save()", "after file");
                 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                 Log.i("in save()", "after outputstream");
                 bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                 out.flush();
                 out.close();
                 Log.i("in save()", "after outputstream closed");
                 // MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                 //filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(),filename.getName());

                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                         "File has been saved to " + showPathInToast , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple AsyncTask. You specify the destination File in the constructor and the url when calling execute. It simply reads the InputStream until it returns nothing and directly writes into the destination File using a FileOutputStream.

```
private class FileDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    File destination;

    public FileDownloadTask(File destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();

            if(!destination.exists()) {
                if(!destination.mkdirs()) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((is.read(bytes) >= 0)) {
                fos.write(bytes);
            }

            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you can add your ProgressDialog logic again.